# Error when installing Apache Spark and running spark-shell on Mac

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to install Apache Spark on my Mac (OSX Big Sur) and unfortunately can't get it to work. These are the steps that I took:

1. Installed JAVA
2. Set JAVA_HOME in the .zshenv file
   `export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-16.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home`
3. Used Homebrew to install Scala
4. Used Homebrew to install Apache-Spark
   `brew install apache-spark`
5. Set SPARK_HOME in the .zshrc file

```
export SPARK_HOME=/Users/fabi/Spark/spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2
export PATH=$PATH:$SPARK_HOME/bin.
```

Now, when running spark-shell, this is the message I get:

```
fabi@Fabians-MacBook-Pro-2 ~ % spark-shell
21/06/05 19:41:16 WARN Utils: Your hostname, Fabians-MacBook-Pro-2.local resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.0.1; using 192.168.0.17 instead (on interface en0)
21/06/05 19:41:16 WARN Utils: Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.apache.spark.unsafe.array.ByteArrayMethods.<clinit>(ByteArrayMethods.java:54)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.config.package$.<init>(package.scala:1095)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.config.package$.<clinit>(package.scala)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitArguments.$anonfun$loadEnvironmentArguments$3(SparkSubmitArguments.scala:157)
    at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:447)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitArguments.loadEnvironmentArguments(SparkSubmitArguments.scala:157)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitArguments.<init>(SparkSubmitArguments.scala:115)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2$$anon$3.<init>(SparkSubmit.scala:1022)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.parseArguments(SparkSubmit.scala:1022)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1039)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1048)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make private java.nio.DirectByteBuffer(long,int) accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.nio" to unnamed module @40f9161a
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:357)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.checkCanSetAccessible(Constructor.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.setAccessible(Constructor.java:181)
    at org.apache.spark.unsafe.Platform.<clinit>(Platform.java:56)
    ... 13 more
fabi@Fabians-MacBook-Pro-2 ~ %
```

Happy to receive help from you guys after spending my afternoon changing and reinstalling everything with no success.

Best
Fabian